# estoy tratando de subir mi pagina a un hosting 000webhost

Tags: php, html, mysql, hosting

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy ingresar no me carga la pagina que sigue que seria esta y se queda en el error, añado código HTML y el código PHP

Cuando le doy a salir no me carga la pagina inicial sino que se queda en blanco y no va a ningún lado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilosingre.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ingresar.php" method="post">
        <table width = '40%' border = '1'>
            <tr><td colspan="2" class="titulo">Acceso</td></tr>
            <br>
            <tr><td align="center" rowspan="5"><label class="logo">M & M</label><td><label>Usuario</label></td></td></tr>
            <br>
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="txtnomUsuario" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td><label>Contraseña</label></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="password" name="txtpassword" required></td></tr>
            <div class="row btn btn-block"></div>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="ingresar">
            <button class="btn" href="veterinaria.html">Salir</button></td></tr>
            </div>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
include ('abrir.php');

if(!$conexion){
    die("Conexion no establecida ".mysql_connect_error());
}

$nombre = $_POST ['txtnomUsuario'];
$pass = $_POST ['txtpassword'];

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM registro WHERE usuario = '".$nombre."' and pass = '".$pass."'");

$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($nr == 1){
    echo "<script>alert('Bienvenido'); window.location='/proyectophp/ProyectoFinal/historial.html'</script>";
    if($nr == 0 ||$nr == 0){
    echo '<script>alert("Nombre de usuario o contraseña incorrectos");</script>';
    include ('ingresar.html');
    echo "Ingreso no autorizado";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a realizar el [tour]. La ruta a la que dirige es `/proyectophp/ProyectoFinal/historial.html` puede que la ruta no sea correcta como la subiste, puedes dejar la estructura de carpetas y archivos de tu proyecto, tambien la url donde te marca el error 404

Comment: cual es la estructura de los directorios de tu hosting? tienes tu `index.html` en la raíz del directorio? agrega más detalles a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: por otra parte, no es muy recomendable mezclar php con html, y si lo haces la extensión del archivo debe ser `.php`  y cualquier cosa debe de estar por encima de la declaración del html

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo, son fallas muy simples.

primero el error 404, se debe a que no encuentra "ingresar.php"

comprueba que los archivos html y php estén en la misma ruta

```
WEB
paginaweb.com/ingresar.html
paginaweb.com/ingresar.php

HOSTING
/public_html/ingresar.html
/public_html/ingresar.php
```

según veo en la dirección js una vez efectuado el php que tienes el proyecto separado en carpetas, en el mismo caso anterior, comprueba que están en la misma ruta

```
WEB
paginaweb.com/proyectophp/ProyectoFinal/ingresar.html
paginaweb.com/proyectophp/ProyectoFinal/ingresar.php
paginaweb.com/proyectophp/ProyectoFinal/historial.html

HOSTING
/public_html/proyectophp/ProyectoFinal/ingresar.html
/public_html/proyectophp/ProyectoFinal/ingresar.php
/public_html/proyectophp/ProyectoFinal/historial.html
```

te recomiendo que no uses carpetas para los proyectos, hazlo directamente en el dominio principal o crea un sub dominio

```
paginaweb.com/ingresar.html
subdominio.paginaweb.com/ingresar.html
```

si indagas el tema de las rutas, lograras solucionar el error 404
por otro lado, puede a que se deba a lo que menciono @christian en el comentario, desde el explorador de archivos -> vista detallada, comprueba que los archivos tengan su extensión correspondientes a "html" y "php"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que si intentas ingresar una dirección html y el archivo esta en php, se produce el error 404

```
paginaweb.com/archivo.html
/public_html/archivo.php
```

es el mismo caso en viceversa

```
paginaweb.com/archivo.php
/public_html/archivo.html
```

y el boton de salir, no te funciona por que esta mal escrito

```
<button class="btn" href="veterinaria.html">Salir</button>
```

el atributo "href" sirve para la etiqueta "a" que se usa normalmente para enlaces

```
<a class="btn" href="veterinaria.html">Salir</a>
```

si quieres hacerlo funcionar con la etiqueta "button" tienes que integrarle js

```
<button onClick="javascript:window.location.href='veterinaria.html'">Salir</button>
```

otra cosa que esta mal es que repites la condicional aquí

```php
if($nr == 0 ||$nr == 0)
```

no hace falta repetir la misma sentencia, con una sola basta para que compruebe la condicional

```php
if($nr == 0)
```